# Debugging Uncaught Exceptions or All Exceptions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

You can clearly see in the picture here that you used to be able to break on all or uncaught exceptions in vscode:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome

On the current version of vscode and this plugin (vscode 1.1.1, chrome-debug 0.3.1) those checkboxes seem to be gone from the Breakpoints section of the debug window.

Was that feature moved, or is it not available anymore?